# Failed to render autoLayout Status, the agent crashed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

I have recently received this error "Failed to render autoLayout Status, the agent crashed" ever since updating to IOS 12. The previous fix was to put this in my pod file and it worked up until IOS 12. Now it's actually crashing the auto layout which makes it so I can't edit anything.

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
    config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
end
end
```

I tried the whole fix of deleting the derived data with no avail. My current Cocoapod version is

```
.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods.rb
```

Any solutions as of yet to this IOS 12 bug?

[image]